# Facebook Page Public Access Content permission: competitive analysis and benchmarking only?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to write a backend application that retrieves public posts from Facebook pages that I don't manage, using the graph API. As an example the last 5 posts of the local pub page.
According to the [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/page/feed) documentation, I need to manage the page or request the [Page Public Content Access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS).

The Page Public Content Access permission is mentioning the following as allowed usage: 'Provide aggregated, anonymized public content for competitive analysis and benchmarking'.
This sounds very restricted to me.

Is it possible and allowed to let my backend application retrieve public Facebook posts and show them in my mobile application as feature?

Most references on StackOverflow refer to issues that are related to API changes that have been made.
I'm trying to understand what is allowed and what not but it is hard for me to extract this from the documentation on the developers page.